# Apply CSS at module level in angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, stylesheet

I have developed an application with three big modules. I want to apply some common CSS to 2 modules but the third module will have a different CSS. I do not want to apply the css of the first 2 modules to the third module.

I cannot apply css at component level because each module has many sub modules, component and sub components.

Please suggest a way to implement the CSS at module level.

**Thanks In Advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, right now you can't do that. It is a pending feature (See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9890) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11682)).

However you can apply style to bootstrapped component of your module with /deep/ strategy. [See this](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by manually loading and unloading of css modules from a root/parent component of a module which will also take effect to child module of current parent module.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027237/apply-different-css-files-between-2-sub-roots/66027914#66027914) for explanation.

Answer (score -1):

In an Angular app you should use `::ng-deep` since `/deep/` and `>>>` are deprecated. [This link](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) might help.

Comment: I can not make changes  in CSS file. becuase I have used one admin template. That template have list of class. is there any other way to implement it ?