# Apply different css files between 2 sub roots

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have an angular app, which consists of a website and system.
so I have made 2 sub roots under app root, websiteMaster, and systemMaster.
CSS files of the website don't have to be loaded when I'm logged in.
CSS files of the systems don't have to be loaded when I'm logged out.
so I need to load CSS files in websiteMaster only for website sub root components and to load CSS files in systemMaster only for system sub root components.

Is there a way to apply that using Angular 8?

Answer (score 1):

You've to manually load/unload css files in a main/root(whatever you want to call it) component in one of your subroot module.
Let suppose websiteMaster module has following structure

Routes:

```
// Wrapping all routes in a parent component
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: WebsiteMasterRootComponent, children: [
    { path: 'any-path', component: AnyComponent },
    { path: 'any-other-path', component: AnyOtherComponent },
  ]
}];
```

WebsiteMasterRootComponent: which will load and unload css files related to this module

```
export class WebsiteMasterRootComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
// css files required for current module
private styles = [
  { id: 'css-file-1', path: 'assets/css/css-file-1.css' },
  { id: 'css-file-2', path: 'assets/css/css-file-2.css' },
  { id: 'css-file-3', path: 'assets/css/css-file-3.css' },
];
constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.styles.forEach(style => this.loadCss(style));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  // remove css files from DOM when component is getting destroying
  this.styles.forEach(style => {
    let element = document.getElementById(style.id);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  });
}

// append css file to DOM dynamically when current module is loaded
private loadCss(style: any) {
  let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  let link = document.createElement('link');
  link.id = style.id;
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.href = style.path;
  head.appendChild(link);
}}
```